# Can I install a higher Mhz RAM alongside a slower one?

Tags: memory, ddr3, amd-phenom

I have a computer which currently has:

- **Motherboard:** MSI 880GMA-E45 motherboard
- **Processor:** AMD Phenom II X6 1090T CPU.
- **RAM:** 8Gb DDR3 1333MHz Dual Channel Corsair RAM

I've been given some new RAM by a colleague: 8GB DDR3 1600MHz Dual Channel Kingston RAM

If I installed these new RAM modules in my PC will they be compatible?

Answer (score 5):

Your motherboard supports DDR3 1600 (even if it is noted as *(OC) at the MSI homepage), but your CPU does not (only up to DDR3 1333). Therefore, if you build in you DDR3 1600 memory, it will most likely automatically be underclocked to work with your CPU.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Would it be worth my while adding the extra 8Gb if it's going to underclocked to 1333MHz to work with my current CPU?

Comment: Adding up to 16GB is never false, more RAM is always better. Of course, this depends on what you want to do with the machine. Normally, you will not need more the 4-8 GB, but if you work with virtual machines like me, more then 8GB really comes in handy.

Comment: I'll add the extra 8Gb to the machine in that case, as I run a linux distro and OSX in virtualboxes. Thanks for response.